# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 10:18. StaticResource not found for key TwoButtonTopBarTemplate

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I keep getting this error:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 10:18. StaticResource not found for key TwoButtonTopBarTemplate.
```

I am trying to use a template I made on this page, works on a different page when I do it the same way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<likeit:InformationPage
    xmlns:likeit="clr-namespace:LikeIT" 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:devsdna="clr-namespace:DevsDNA;assembly=DevsDNA.GradientBoxView"
    x:Class="LikeIT.News">

    <ContentView x:Name="newsContentView"
        ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TwoButtonTopBarTemplate}" HeightRequest="100">

        <StackLayout Spacing="3">
...
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</likeit:InformationPage>
```

Of course I am using this in my .cs file.

```
public partial class News : InformationPage
```

My TwoButtonTopBarTemplate is defined in App

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:abstractions="clr-namespace:RoundedBoxView.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=RoundedBoxView.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
    x:Class="LikeIT.forms.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="TwoButtonTopBarTemplate">
...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your template defined? Could you please share its code, too?

Comment: Where have you defined `TwoButtonTopBarTemplate`

Comment: I added it, @G.hakim

Comment: Since you haven't added any actual code without which we are crippled i suggest you read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating

Comment: I did add code...?

Comment: Can you please share the code inside `ControlTemplate` ? I just tested the code you post and it works well on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public App()
    {
        MainPage = new MainPage();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

should have been

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```